# maybe stupid question: If a single java app on a separate server is causing 23Gigs of Binlogs to be sent to the db replica

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

does this mean there is 23gb of traffic (or more ) moving between the Java app (server) and the master Mysql server?

this has been bugging me.

The reason why I ask is because we have one server that is dedicated to our App.  Nothing else connects to the DB.  Our Binlogs on the master average about 23gigs per day.

does this make sense?

Comment: just to add: there are no other databases on the db servers.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else connects to the DB look at Bytes_received from a mysql show status; query 24 hours apart.